# is there a way to grab a value from an object via its key?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
el: "#app",
data: {

songs : { 

songNames: [{holiday:'mp3/01.mp3'}, {loveme:'mp3/02.mp3'}, {byebye:'mp3/03.mp3'}],

        }

songCheck: ['byebye'],
foundSong: new Audio (" "),
```

Hello,
I want to get the value "mp3/03.mp3" from the songNames Array by cheking with songCheck Array item and assigning the returned "mp3/03.mp3" to the variable like this:

```
foundSong: new Audio ("mp3/03.mp3 "),
```

then

```
this.foundSong.play();
```

please help me. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I don't understand everything you want, maybe this snippet will help you solving your problem:

```js
const songNames = [{holiday:'mp3/01.mp3'}, {loveme:'mp3/02.mp3'}, {byebye:'mp3/03.mp3'}];

// 1. Key you are looking for
const searchKey = "byebye";

// 2. Find object we are looking for
// - .find loops over all songNames objects
// - for each object we check if it has property we are looking for i.e. "byebye"
// - first object that match criteria is returned or undefined if there are no matches
const searchResult = songNames.find(song => song.hasOwnProperty(searchKey));

// 3. Get desired value from object
console.log(searchResult && searchResult[searchKey]); // will return "mp3/03.mp3" in our case where searchKey is "byebye"
```

Comment: thanks alot, it workded and is also a short solution.

Answer (score 1):

It's not pretty, but here's what I've come up with:

```
var data = {
  songs : { 
    songNames: [
      {holiday:'mp3/01.mp3'}, 
      {loveme:'mp3/02.mp3'}, 
      {byebye:'mp3/03.mp3'}
    ]
  },

  songCheck: ['byebye'],
  foundSong: ""
};

for (var i = 0; i < data.songs.songNames.length; i++)
{
  console.log(data.songs.songNames[i]);

  if (data.songs.songNames[i][data.songCheck[0]] != undefined)
  {
    data.foundSong = data.songs.songNames[i][data.songCheck[0]];
    break;
  }
}

console.log(data.foundSong);
```

I don't have the `Audio` object, so I couldn't use it, but that's a minor change.

What I'd actually suggest, if you have the authority/access or can convince those who do have it, to change the data structure a bit. Give your `songNames` object a different structure, like an actual object.

```
{
  name: "holiday",
  filename: "mp3/01.mp3"
}
```

And then revert `songCheck` to a simple string. Doing both of these suggestsions gets rid of some of the extra complexity and you don't have to rely on odd behavior, which is more of a hack than anything. Checking for an `undefined` value when using an object key isn't good in this instance. For instance, if someone wants to change the data structure later, you'll have to change this code later anyway, and it'll be harder to find this code when it happens.

Thinking about this further, it might make sense in your original code to do it your way, but doesn't make sense when stripped down for this Question, so I guess take that advice with a grain of salt.

BTW, there's some null checking that you should do in the above code, that I've left out.

Comment: thank you it worked with my current structure, but didn't worked with your recommended structure. what should change in order to use  {
  name: "holiday",
  filename: "mp3/01.mp3"
}

Comment: @Fereydoon, change `if (data.songs.songNames[i][data.songCheck[0]] != undefined)` to `if (data.songs.songNames[i].name === data.songCheck[0])`. If you don't know how to use objects, check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects . You might also want to make it case insensitive, by using toLowerCase or toUpperCase. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase